# Unsetting diplay:block

Tags: css, properties, block

I wanna set block dsiplay:block every where in the site for input expect in select options input. How can i unset display:block ?

Comment: How can `input { display: block; }` apply to a `select`?

Comment: @Bolt sorry i am using checkbox :P

Comment: `select` is not a checkbox...

Comment: @BoltClock i am using CakePHP and we set type=>select and multiple for a series of checkbox. terminology mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must overwrite the css property with an other like this

```
select {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
display: inline;
```

Read the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp), it will show you all the values other than 'block'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following this will remove the block

display:inline

Simples....

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `unset`. I'm not sure how well it's supported, but it works in both [Firefox and Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unset).

```
.everything { display: block; }
.my-input   { display: unset; }
```